# How to append the root element of partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my main view of ASP.NET MVC project, I am rendering a partial view once and then on click of add button I want to append the partial view to the form. But when I click add, only the child element  ...  is added to the MainView. How can I append the root element of my partial view (_roll.cshtml)?

MainView.cshtml

```
<div id="rolls">
    @Html.Partial("_roll")
</div>

<br />

<div class="row">
    <button id="addRoll" class="btn"></button>
</div>
```

_roll.cshtml

```
<div class="roll">
    <div class="row">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

.js

```
$(function () {
    $('#addRoll').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#rolls').append($('.roll').html());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to just use the element itself and not its innerHTML (.html()):

```
$(function () {
    var $rolls = $('#rolls'), $role = $('.roll:first');
    $('#addRoll').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //$rolls.append($('.roll')); // wont work since you want to append the same element to the same parent
        $rolls.append($role.clone());
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried adding without .html() but that doesn't do anything. The main view doesn't change with this.

Comment: Cloning works but it brings down the values entered within the text boxes in the roll.row div, not what I wanted. The rows added should be empty. Sorry, I had ... in the row section, but it has some text boxes and dropdowns to be filled out.

Comment: @AloofC yes thats expected, You can use templating for that... Since you did not provide your complete html i dint do that way.. What kind of elements you have? Or try this way http://jsfiddle.net/UUeYH/

Comment: Thanks. That works, :first selector is not really needed I think.

Comment: @AloofC yes thats because i am using `[0]`

Comment: One example where this doesn't work. If I don't have the first partial view rendered but still want to add partial view on click of add button. So my MainView.cshtml would originally just have <div id="rolls">
    
</div>

Comment: @AloofC ofcourse if you dont have partial view where will you get the corresponding html structure from? This is where you can use templating.

Comment: how do you suggest moving this partial view code into a template? HTML5 has a new template element but seems like may not be supported yet everywhere.

Comment: @AloofC for temporary purpose, render the partial view in a script element like `<script type="text/html" id="rolesTemplate">@Html.Partial("_roll")</script>`, and append the contents of `rolesTemplate` like `.append($('#rolesTemplate').html())` Try this way.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use the OuterHTML of the element if you want.